# Parsing out abnormal characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I have to work with text that was previously copy/pasted from an excel document into a .txt file. There are a few characters that I assume mean something to excel but that show up as an unrecognised character (i.e. that '?' symbol in gedit, or one of those rectangles in some other text editors.). I wanted to parse those out somehow, but I'm unsure of how to do so. I know regular expressions can be helpful, but there really isn't a pattern that matches unrecognisable characters. How should I set about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could work with http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/ maybe to read / parse the data

Comment: will that lib work on a linux machine? I was looking at a similar library earlier and it was only for windows.

Comment: why should it not work on linux machines? ruby and ruby gems work also on a linux machine

Comment: I have no idea, perhaps to do with version differences of the excel program. Anyways, its good to know this lib will work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're getting these characters because the text file contains invalid Unicode characters, that means your '?'s and triangles could actually be unrecognized multi byte sequences.

If you want to properly handle the spreadsheet contents, i recommend you to first export the data to CSV using (Open|Libre)Office and choosing UTF-8 as file encoding.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Answer (score 1):

If you are not worried about multi byte sequences I find this regex to be handy:

```
line.gsub( /[^0-9a-zA-Z\-_]/, '*' )
```

Comment: thanks man, Im going to try the methods posted here and see which one is the best suited to the task.